# Animating while playing timeline isn't working

Tags: animation

I used to hit play in the timeline and then rotate or move a bone around. The action would be recorded and then I'd clean up. Now it's not working at all. can anyone help? this is really important to me.

BTW: The Auto Keying is on. I've done it for years like this. but for some reason, it doesn't work with 3.0. I skipped a lot of versions in 2.9 but it worked with 2.91. now it doesn't. I'm hoping it's not a bug but a setting I'm missing.

Comment: i just tested it with 3.0 and 3.1. it worked on both versions. What OS do you have and did you try downloading the latest 3.0 version? if downloading the latest version doesn't work, please provide blend file

Comment: well, I just tried it and it worked. same file, just rebooted my computer. maybe it was a memory issue?

Answer (score 1):

it's only recorded if you press this "autokey" button before:

[image]